# WP7 browser control won't invoke javascript Error 80020101

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have the following:

```
public MainPage()
{
    webBrowser1.ScriptNotify += new EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs>(webBrowser1_ScriptNotify);
}

void webBrowser1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    // ... some code ...
    webBrowser1.InvokeScript("nativeCallback", response.Serialize());
}
```

The script notify is triggered when a user presses a button on the web page. I am trying to invoke the JavaScript below but i keep getting Error 80020101.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nativeCallback(e){
        document.getElementById('callbackDiv').appendChild("<b>" + e + "</b>");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`80020101` means that there is a problem compiling the function ready to execute it.
The problem is that `appendChild()` is expecting a node to be passed and you're giving it a string.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function nativeCallback(e){ 
          var b = document.createElement('b');
          b.innerHTML = e;
          document.getElementById('callbackDiv').appendChild(b);
    } 
</script>
```

You can also access `callbackDiv` directly:

```
callbackDiv.appendChild(b);
```