# How to properly attach event listerner on each link on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, addeventlistener, getelementsbytagname

I have the following code which attach event listeners on each link on a HTML document.

The problem is that the `evt.target.href` always return the last link on the page instead of the exact link that raise the event. What am I missing?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('MSGestureHold', eventListener, false);
    links[i].addEventListener('MSPointerDown', eventListener, false);
    gestureHandler = new MSGesture();
    gestureHandler.target = links[i];
};

function eventListener(evt) {
    if (evt.type == 'MSPointerDown') {
        gestureHandler.addPointer(evt.pointerId);
        return;
    }

    if (evt.detail & evt.MSGESTURE_FLAG_BEGIN) {
        window.external.notify(evt.target.href);
    }
};
```

**EDIT**
I should mention that I am developing for Windows Phone and use the browser control which runs IE10. So I am not concern about compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear about your question but I think you are trying to do this

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

function eventListener(evt, gestureHandler) {
    if (evt.type == 'MSPointerDown') {
        gestureHandler.addPointer(evt.pointerId);
        return;
    }

    if (evt.detail & evt.MSGESTURE_FLAG_BEGIN) {
        window.external.notify(evt.target.href);
    }
};

[].forEach.call(links, function (link) {
    link.addEventListener('MSGestureHold', function (evt) {
        var gestureHandler = new MSGesture();

        gestureHandler.target = link;
        eventListener(evt, gestureHandler);
    }, false);

    link.addEventListener('MSPointerDown', function (evt) {
        var gestureHandler = new MSGesture();

        gestureHandler.target = link;
        eventListener(evt, gestureHandler);
    }, false);
});
```

Note: this could be further optimised

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am trying to do. However I get an error  `An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.`. That's raised in Visual Studio when trying to invoke the script. I think something in the `forEach` loop is causing the error.

Comment: That is clearly a separate issue, you should read some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=80020101+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: One of the results that is related to WP browser control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501058/wp7-browser-control-wont-invoke-javascript-error-80020101 . It appears that if we pass a wrong type in the function parameter, this error will be raised. But not sure how it's related to the code above

Comment: The above code is perfectly valid, but I have no idea how you use MSGesture and its related bits, perhaps that is the problem. I'm afraid that I can not be of further assistance there. Do you not get any line number associated with the error so that you can narrow down the issue?

Comment: I use `browser.InvokeScript("execScript", gestureHold);` to invoke the script where gestureHold is a string representing the whole script. So the error only indicate it occured on the `InvokeScript` line

Comment: Sorry, I don't use any MS products. I can only suggest that you investigate a far as you possibly can and then post a question specific to that issue in the hope that someone can give you some kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

you did not define gestureHandler as a var so it is a global to which you constantly set a new value..

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');  
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    { 
        links[i].addEventListener('MSGestureHold', eventListener, false); 
        links[i].addEventListener('MSPointerDown', eventListener, false); 
        var gestureHandler = new MSGesture(); // <--- notice the var, only local 
        gestureHandler.target = links[i]; 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JQuery or Prototype for that, otherwise it won't be cross browser compatible.
Same goes for MSPointerEvents, which are IE only.

JQuery example:

```
$('#foo').bind({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```

If you don't want to use libraries (but I highly recommend you look into them) you should use this:

```
var addEvent = function (el, ev, fn) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn);
    } else {
        el['on' + ev] = fn;
    }
};
```

And now to actually try and answer your question:
Events bubble up, so if you place a link inside a link you'll trigger both events if you click inside the child element.

Comment: I can't use any library as I am developing for Windows phone and use the browser control that comes with it. The app I am developing is a browser app so I have no control over how the page is structured. I am not too familiar with Javascript actually, can you share an example how can I rewrite the code as per your example?